# Simple event watching with testrpc - unexpected output

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, events, testrpc

Working with [this example](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7416/event-result-parameters-and-arguments-in-console), I've been attempting to utilise event watching from the web js api.

**Window 1** (a testrpc instance with filled account):

```
testrpc -a 1
```

**Window 2**

```
geth attach rpc:http://localhost:8545
```

in javascript api (abi created from from contract [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7416/event-result-parameters-and-arguments-in-console) - should be copy-pastable):

```
var test1Contract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"getval","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"b","type":"uint256"}],"name":"multiply","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"msg","type":"string"},{"indexed":false,"name":"x","type":"uint256"}],"name":"event_res","type":"event"}]);
var test1 = test1Contract.new(
   {
     from: web3.eth.accounts[0], 
     data: '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', 
     gas: '4700000'
   }, function (e, contract){
    console.log(e, contract);
    if (typeof contract.address !== 'undefined') {
         console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
    }
 })
var interface = [{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"getval","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"b","type":"uint256"}],"name":"multiply","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"msg","type":"string"},{"indexed":false,"name":"x","type":"uint256"}],"name":"event_res","type":"event"}];
var testing = web3.eth.contract(interface).at(test1.address);
var event = testing.event_res(function(error, result) {
    if (!error)
        console.log(result.args);
    else
        console.log(error);
});
var result = testing.multiply.sendTransaction(5,{from : web3.eth.coinbase},function(err,result){
        if(err)
        console.log(err);
});
```

This returns

```
> [object Object]
[object Object]
```

Whereas I'm expecting, from the [original question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7416/event-result-parameters-and-arguments-in-console):

```
{ msg: 'the value after multiplying is:',
  x: { [String: '5'] s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 5 ] } }
```

**Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong?**

Note:

In the first window I get something like, with `eth_getFilterChanges` repeated:

```
...
eth_getFilterChanges
eth_getFilterChanges
eth_getFilterChanges
eth_getFilterChanges
eth_coinbase
eth_sendTransaction

  Transaction: 0x3d716c20e03d8fd7009f532102391c9e7c67f7447180cd180de03436de27e7d
3
  Gas usage: 0x6fee
  Block Number: 0x06
  Block Time: Thu Apr 06 2017 11:42:55 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
eth_getFilterChanges
eth_getFilterChanges
...
```

Answer (score 0):

After seeing [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/12898/820), I (partially) got around the problem by using `JSON.stringify`:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(result.args));
```